# 403 forbidden access denied s3 bucket putobject

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Why I am getting 403 access denied to **s3.putObject**
If i upload file first time, its uploaded successfully, but second time it is giving error.

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
        Bucket: myBucket,
        Key: myKey,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
        ContentType: 'text/plain'
    },(error, url) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('S3 url - '+url); 
                    context.succeed(url);
                }
            });
```

But if i did any update in lambda and try to upload file, it is successfully and uploading second time showing same error

Comment: There is no difference in Amazon S3 if a file is being uploaded for the first time, or being overwritten. You are creating a pre-signed URL that has an expiry time (in seconds). Are you sure that the time simply hasn't expired?

Comment: Every time i am creating new pre-signed url with new expiry time.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error is 403 - forbidden. Scenario is like  i will do any changes in lambda and created pre-signed url using lamda. I used pre-signed url to upload file which is working fine only one time. after that second time using same lamda i creating pre-signed url and if i consume that url using http.put it gives me error 403- forbidden